# Does "reverse sound technology" make headphones safer?

Tags: consumer-products, safety, sound, ear, hearing

Purebuds Earphones claims that their use of "Reverse Sound Technology" makes their earbuds safer, preventing hearing damage. I searched for a scientific study of this technology, or at least a good explanation of it, but couldn't find much.

From what I can understand, the speaker in the earbud is pointed away from the ear, so the sound isn't emitted directly into the ear canal.

From reading reviews of the earbuds, they are actually quite loud and the bass is just as prominent if not more so.

Has Purebuds' claim that their earbuds are safer ever been scientifically tested?

[Link to the earbuds](http://www.purebudsrevolution.com/rs.php) (dead; see [archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20150805112610/http://www.purebudsrevolution.com/rs.php) backup)

Comment: Some references to sources for the claims would improve the question.

Comment: @matt_black The website that is linked to includes the claim.

Comment: [This patent](http://www.google.com/patents/US20020080990) might provide some information for anyone investigating the answer.  "...the high sound pressure waves can be avoided to impact directly on our eardrums so as to eliminate the painful and itchy sensation on our eardrums where the symptoms of middle ear injury that traditional earphones may cause."

Comment: Sounds like you would have to write them first and ask what *exactly* "Reverse Sound Technology" is. Also: what their specific claim is about making them safer, and what studies they have to support that claim.

Comment: Related: https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/42074/do-noise-cancelling-headphones-protect-hearing